# Msysgit GPG error during commit signing

Tags: git, gpg

I'm getting the following error on Windows with msysgit. Doesn't matter whether or not I am doing it from the command prompt or the BASH bundled with Git:

> gpg: error loading `iconv.dll': The specified module could not be found.

Google hasn't yielded any good results yet. Any idea of how to get around this? I see libiconv2.dll in the same bin folder as gpg.exe.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://www.gnupg.org/download/iconv.en.html) page for the dll and how to install it

The directions are as follows:

> Installing iconv.dll
>
> To support different languages and character sets, Microsoft Windows
>   versions of GnuPG make use of a DLL called "iconv.dll". This DLL has
>   been written by the GNU project too and is used by several
>   applications ported from GNU/Linux to MS Windows systems. If this
>   library has not yet been installed on your system, an error message
>   might have you taken to this page. Please follow the instructions
>   below to install this library.
>
> GnuPG has a fallback mechanism to work even without this DLL. However
>   some texts may not show up correclty and when creating a new key it
>   might not be encoded correctly. Thus unless you are using the Latin-1
>   or UTF-8 character set, you should definitley install the DLL before
>   you create a new key or add a new user ID to a key.
>
> If you have used the Gpgwin package to install GnupG, you should never
>   see this message because this DLL will get installed. However, it
>   might happen that such a DLL has been insatlled on your system by
>   another application and later be deinstalled. To rectify this, simply
>   re-install Gpg4win and your are done.
>
> The DLL is available as a ZIP file at the address
>   ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/binary/libiconv-1.9.1.dll.zip. You should
>   also get the corresponding ".sig" file and verify the integrity . This
>   DLL has been built from the source package libiconv-1.9.1.tar.gz
>   available at the same FTP sites. We distribute it separately for
>   convenience and because GnuPG only requires this DLL and not the other
>   files from the binary package. For copying conditions see the included
>   file "COPYING.LIB".
>
> To install this DLL, unzip it and copy the file "iconv.dll" to a
>   directory where you usually keep DLLs. If you don't know such a
>   directory, it is safe to copy it into the same directory as the
>   "gpg.exe" file is stored.